# Many to many association not returning associated table

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, many-to-many

I'm trying to add 'roles' to users - each user can have multiple roles, and roles aren't limited to a number of users - they can be assigned to as many users as is needed. I followed a few tutorials, read through quite a few stackoverflow questions/answers, and still can't seem to get this to work.

**user.model.js**

```
'use strict';
const { Model } = require('sequelize');
const PROTECTED_ATTRIBUTES = ['password'];

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {
    toJSON() {
      // hide protected fields
      const attributes = { ...this.get() };
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-syntax
      for (const a of PROTECTED_ATTRIBUTES) {
        delete attributes[a];
      }
      return attributes;
    }
    
    static associate(models) {
      User.belongsToMany(models.Role, {
        through: 'UserRoles',
        as: 'roles',
        foreignKey: 'roleId'
      });
    }
    
    
  }
  User.init({
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    lastLoginAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: true
    },
    lastIPAddress: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'User',
    paranoid: true,
    tableName: 'users'
  });
  return User;
};
```

**role.model.js**

```
'use strict';
const { Model } = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Role extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      Role.belongsToMany(models.User, {
        through: 'UserRoles',
        as: 'users',
        foreignKey: 'userId'
      });
    }
  };
  Role.init({
    roleName: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Role',
  });
  return Role;
};
```

**userroles.model.js**

```
'use strict';
const { Model } = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class UserRoles extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
    }
  };
  UserRoles.init({
    userId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    roleId: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'UserRoles',
  });
  return UserRoles;
};
```

**user.controller.js**

```
async function getUsers(req, res, next) {
    const name = req.query.name;
    const condition = name ? { name: { [Op.like]: `%${name}%` } } : null;
    
    User.findAll({ where: condition, include: { model: Role, as: 'roles'} })
        .then(data => {
            res.send(data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            const error = new createError(500, 'Some error occurred while retrieving users.');
            return next(error);
        });
}
```

The query returns a 'roles' array, but nothing is inside it even though the UserRoles table has an entry assigned to an existing user and existing role.

The query it generates, in case that helps:

```
 SELECT "User"."id", "User"."name", "User"."email", "User"."password", "User"."lastLoginAt", "User"."lastIPAddress", "User"."createdAt", "User"."updatedAt", "User"."deletedAt", "roles"."id" AS "roles.id", "rol
es"."roleName" AS "roles.roleName", "roles"."createdAt" AS "roles.createdAt", "roles"."updatedAt" AS "roles.updatedAt", "roles->UserRoles"."userId" AS "roles.UserRoles.userId", "roles->UserRoles"."roleId" AS "roles.UserRoles.role
Id", "roles->UserRoles"."createdAt" AS "roles.UserRoles.createdAt", "roles->UserRoles"."updatedAt" AS "roles.UserRoles.updatedAt" FROM "users" AS "User" LEFT OUTER JOIN ( "UserRoles" AS "roles->UserRoles" INNER JOIN "role" AS "ro
les" ON "roles"."id" = "roles->UserRoles"."roleId") ON "User"."id" = "roles->UserRoles"."roleId" WHERE ("User"."deletedAt" IS NULL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**role.model.js**

```
'use strict';
const {Model} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    class Role extends Model {
        static associate(models) {
            //...
            Role.belongsToMany(models.UserRoles, {
                as: 'userRoles',
                foreignKey: 'roleId',
            });
        }
    }
    // ...
    return Role;
};
```

```
User.findAll({where: condition, include: {model: Role, as: 'roles', include: ['userRoles']}})
                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```